# How to always return index.html Tomcat

Tags: angular, tomcat, error-handling, routes

I have an Angular application running live on Tomcat, but since I have implemented routing, if I visit a url manually I get a `404` not found. Also when an error occurs, it's a basic server page, not my error url page.

How do I configure Tomcat to always return `index.html` on routing and on errors? I know the set up, as I have done it with a different server, I'm just new to Tomcat and couldn't find anything online.

From my understanding, it's a pretty straightforward few lines of code in other back-end languages, I just can't find any info on Tomcat.

Answer (score 3):

Basically you have to change `web.xml` file inside `conf` folder of the Tomcat directory: `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/web.xml`.

```
<error-page> 
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error/index.html</location>
</error-page>
```

And add a webapp that has the page and will answer to the URL under given location.

Comment: and what about the routing? how do I return index.html for any route?

Comment: I don't think routing in angular should be creating any issue. It will navigate to page you mentioned depending on access privileges to that user. You might be accessing the URL which is not present that's why you are getting 404 error page. If you want to customize that error page you can change with your custom error page.

Comment: Angular is a SPA framework, so during routing, the index.html page must always be returned. think of it as a '/*' pattern