# Route in Angular throws 404 resource not available when refreshed

Tags: angular, tomcat, routes, web-deployment

I deployed my angular application in tomcat, built using `ng build --prod --base-href=/myapp/`, when i try to access a specific route like `http://localhost:8083/myapp/home` using `[routerLink]="['/home']` it works fine, but when try to refresh the page or access directly `http://localhost:8083/myapp/home` from the browser, i get `HTTP Status 404 The requested resource [/myapp/home] is not available`, below is my routing configuration :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'myapp', redirectTo: "/home", pathMatch: "full" },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent }
];
```

**Update :**

I've added below configuration in tomcat, and the 404 error is gone, but now when i refresh the page i'm redirected to default route which is `myapp`, while i'm supposed to be redirected to the current route :

```
<error-page> 
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/index.html</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: You would need to configure tomcat to redirect all requests (404 errors) to `index.html` since you app is a single page application

Comment: how can i configure that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47909980/3055401

Comment: yah that works, but when i'm in another route other then 'home', and i refresh i'm redirected to default route which is myapp

Comment: Unfortunately, I have never used tomcat to host a single page application so I wouldn't know how to fix that. But I would imagine you just need the "right" configuration for the tomcat server

Comment: You want a rewrite here, not a redirect. A rewrite will keep the url (and therefore your route) in tact.

Comment: how can i do a rewrite?, 404 error are redirected to the index page in tomcat, and since my href is myapp, so the redirect will always be to the default route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by changing `<base href="/">` in index.html to `<base href="./">`

or directly specifying `./` in build :

```
ng build --prod --base-href=./
```